# Changing the value separator of ExamplesTable in JBehave

Tags: jbehave

I faced a problem While using ExamplesTable of JBehave. The default value separator is |, but my example table has got a | character as the data like below.

```
|name|value|
|v4|variablev4|
|v1|var v4|subpart of v4|another part of v4|
```

i tried changing the value of the value separator like below

```
{ignorableSeparator=!--,headerSeparator=!,valueSeparator=!}
!name!value!
!v4!variablev4!
!v1!var v4|subpart of v4|another part of v4!
```

as per http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/model/ExamplesTable.html but found NO LUCK. It is throwing the following error.

```
(org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path '{ignorableSeparator=!--,headerSeparator=!,valueSeparator=!}
```

Any other way to do it? 
or am i doing it wrong somewhere?

I am using

```
jbehave.core.version 3.8
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to is referring to the java type that back up [tabular parameters](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html). I assume you want to use this syntax in the examples table for a [parameterised scenario](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html), is that correct? In this case, I fear, that the using anything but the pipe symbol won't work.

Simple solution: Search & Replace your story files, maybe? (Have you tried escaping the pipe with \| or similar?)

Another idea to try: Provide your own [properties file for internationalization](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/stories-in-your-language.html).

Comment: As per the documentation, if the value separator has to be changed to other than **|** then we will ahve to make use `inline properties` i assume that the inline properties are set in `.story`.
i also tried escaping the pipe with \, but it did not work

Comment: i have to change the value separator only for a particular scenario, if i go with my own properties file then that would affect the whole stories.

Comment: Can you please post the whole scenario, not just the table?

Comment: `Given /us is loaded
When .//*[@id='coherent_id_7']/a is clicked
Then the variables will be:

|name|value|
|v4|D=pageName|
|c19|value of c19|

and expanded variables will be:

|name|value|
|c6|value of c6 | this string is also the value of c6|
|v19|value of v19 | value1 | value2 |`

Answer (score 0):

It should work by defining `||` as the separator:

```
{valueSeparator=||}
|name|value|
||v4||variablev4||
||v1||var v4|subpart of v4|another part of v4||
```